# IDbConnection and Firebird

Tags: c#, .net, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

I want to test dapper micro orm with firebird db and I'm struggle with access to firebird.

Firebird server is up and running, database is populated with some dummy data, and it is stored in c:\mydatabases\test.fdb

Connection string is

```
<add name="testDatabase" connectionString="User=SYSDBA;
           Password=XXX; Database=c:\mydatabases\test.fdb; 
           Data Source=127.0.0.1;" />
```

Inside my repository I'm accessing to the db using IDbConnection

```
private IDbConnection db = 
     new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDatabase"]
         .ConnectionString);
```

but when I'm trying to access data exception is thrown

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error
>   occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was
>   not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server)

Is it possible to use `IDbConnection` with `firebird` and if it's not what do you suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You should use `FBConnection` instead.

Download and reference `FirebirdSql.Data.Firebird` and instead of

```
IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection...
```

use this

```
IDbConnection dbcon = new FbConnection(connectionString);
```

Answer (score 3):

The `SqlConnection` is class specific for SQL Server. What you need to do is download ADO.NET provider for Firebird from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/). This will give you `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` namespace and `FbConnection` class which you can use like this:

```
private IDbConnection db = new FbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testDatabase"].ConnectionString);
```

You can find more examples on how to use Firebird ADO.NET Provider [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-examples-of-use/).